# How to replace characters in python using a loop?

Tags: python, loops, replace, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

First, I have to change all '/' charachter to --> ' x / x ' but nothing happened. After that i have to stop when the loop finds the "modul" --> this part is work.
What's wrong in my code, how can i fix it to change these characters?
Python 2.7.13

```js
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb
import re

filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')
 
f = open('0910000511.txt', 'r')
x = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')

datatable=[]
stop = 0
for ctable in soup.find_all('table',  "ctable" ):
    for record in ctable.find_all('tr'):
        temp_data = []
        for data in record.find_all('td'):
            temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
            if '/' in data.text:
                record2 = str(record).replace('/', ' / ')
                final_format = ' {} '.format(record2)
            if 'modul' in data.text:
                stop = 1
                break
        datatable.append(temp_data)
        if stop == 1:
            break
    if stop == 1:
        break
output.writerows(datatable)

print record2
tab6col = soup.find('table', { "class" : "tab6col" })
datatable2=[]
for record in tab6col.find_all('tr'):
    temp_data2 = []
    for data in record.find_all('td'):
        temp_data2.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
    datatable.append(temp_data2)

output.writerows(datatable)

resultcsv.close()
```

Part of my html code:

```js
<TR><td>&nbsp;</td><TD class="contentsub" WIDTH="80">3/1</TD><TD class="contentword_valid">NAME<BR>
Változás időpontja: 2013.12.30.<BR>
Bejegyzés kelte: 2013.12.19.
```

so i want to change the all / tags for example:  '3/1' to --> ' 3 / 1 '

Comment: post the html content that your are trying to scrape. Not all but some snippet

Comment: i updated my question with the html part

Comment: see my answer below @tardos93

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Replace `record2 = str(record).replace('/', ' / ')` to `record2 = str(record).replace('/', 'x/x')`

Comment: 'x/x' -> x is just a number, i want to replace these formats : '3/1' to this : ' 3 / 1 ' (x is different numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code and found one problem. You are trying to find `td`, `tr` tag in your script whereas `TR` and `TD` tags are there in your html. Below is the code i have tried.

```
a = """<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><TD class="contentsub" WIDTH="80">3/1</tr><td class="contentword_valid">NAME<BR>
Változás időpontja: 2013.12.30.<BR>
Bejegyzés kelte: 2013.12.19."""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
datatable=[]
stop = 0
soup = BeautifulSoup(a, 'html.parser')
for record in soup.find_all('tr'):
    temp_data = []
    for data in record.find_all('td'):
        temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
        record2 = str(record).replace('/', ' / ')
        print(record2)
        final_format = ' {} '.format(record2)
        if 'modul' in data.text:
            stop = 1
            break
    datatable.append(temp_data)
    print(datatable)
    if stop == 1:
        break
```

output:

```
<tr><td> < / td><td class="contentsub" width="80">3 / 1< / td>< / tr>
<tr><td> < / td><td class="contentsub" width="80">3 / 1< / td>< / tr>
[[b'\xa0', b'3/1']]
```

Comment: I edited my question with the full code, i open a txt.file, after im searching these table ("ctable") because i need these table. Check it pls, you misunderstood me.

Comment: check that table tag exists because that can be the only problem otherwise your code is fine also watch for case sensitivity

Comment: there a lot of / sign in my html source but noone happened with them, so there are some problem with this code :\ 
+ i have to place a plus SPACE before the 3 -> ' 3 / 1 ' (so my goal is when i export it to csv i want to holding this format, because excel convert it to date format if im not putting a + space before the number.

Comment: the code i posted works for the html you posted. Now if you find another error or question then you have to ask a new question. Don't increase the scopes of the question like this. Ask another one we will be happy to help you there.

Comment: im reading a txt file whichone im looking these tables and not in a html.parser.

Comment: lxml parser also works with this code. Tried it and got same output

Comment: i tried this code, and nothing happaned, / stay and just get double output like in your code what is totally bad for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148855/discussion-between-arpit-solanki-and-tardos93).